# What is this bird - sound attached - (Atlanta Georgia)?

Tags: species-identification

We live in Atlanta Georgia (northern suburb) & this bird starts singing in the middle of the night !!

And goes on for almost 2 hours without stopping.

Here is the link to it :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3WzrpCj4uKeQ3l5MnJPY1RfcUpiVzkxRHBsWEN4RnYtTlNB

Any way to politely ask him/her to stop singing at night ? :)

Would highly appreciate any help in this regard !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a [Chuck-will's-widow](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Chuck-wills-widow/); click the "sound" icon in that link for the song. They're native to Georgia and sing interminably at night, so the story checks out.

Comment: Thanks ! You are correct ! Now I just need to find out how to put it to sleep at night. Since it sleeps on ground, maybe I can do something..